# Why does Japanese string create unexpected line breaks in PDF?

Tags: html, css, laravel, pdf, dompdf

The following code is the left header div of the pdf.
Although `東京都江東区潮見2-9-15内田洋行幕潮見ｵﾌｨｽ市区町村名市区町村名市区町村` is a one-line string but unexpectedly it breaks into two lines after `東京都江東区潮見2-9-` when it is written on pdf.

```
<div style="width: 94mm;height: 45mm;padding-left:6mm;float: left;margin-right: 50px;font-size: 12px;overflow-wrap: break-word;background:#DECBA4;">
     <div>〒135-8730</div>
     <div>神奈川県幕張本郷張西ﾒｰﾙｱﾄﾞﾚ幕張西</div>
     <div>ﾌｫﾒｰｼ市区町村名市売上区分</div>
     <div>東京都江東区潮見2-9-15内田洋行幕潮見ｵﾌｨｽ市区町村名市区町村名市区町村</div>
     <div>ウチダインフォメーションテクノロジー 株式会社</div>
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;">ＵＩＴ ＴＫ</div>
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;">ｼｽﾃﾑ課ｼｽﾃﾑ課ｼｽﾃﾑ課ｼｽﾃﾑ課ｼｽﾃﾑ課ｼｽ</div>
     <div style="margin-left: 20px;">良夢ﾁｬﾝ良夢ﾁｬﾝ良夢ﾁｬﾝ様</div>
     <div style="font-size: 10px;">お客様コード 00600201001</div>
</div>
```

The following is the generated pdf
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: When loading html file, it works well. I think you can use br tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have **overflow-wrap** in the style. That will turn it into 2 lines when it does not fits.
When pdf creates a file, it can have its own borders and/or padding added to your own.
In conclussion, be sure you have enough space. An easy fix could be reducing the  margins a little bit and trying again.